# Zlib & Gzip using C: Incorrect header check (Z_DATA_ERROR)

Tags: c, gzip, zlib

I am downloading a graph data set in .txt.gz format from [here](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/email-Eu-core.html).
After downloading I am trying to uncompress it using zlib. The code I use is mostly plagiarized from the `zpipe.c` example with changes to use `gzopen`, `gzfread` and `gzclose`, `Z_SYNC_FLUSH` plus `inflateInit2(&stream, (32 + MAX_WBITS))`.
I also tried (16 + MAX_WBITS).

As mentioned in the title the error message I get is `Z_DATA_ERROR (-3)` along with "incorrect header check".

Now the data can be opened with zcat (and zless) and the header seems to be okay, too:

```
1F 8B            gzip  
08               deflate  
00               no special information
33 0c 36 59      last modification
00               no extra flags
03               unix
```

[image: First 32 byte of the gz file]

In short, I don't know what could be wrong.

Below is the code I use.

```
int uncompress_dataset(const char* gz_path, const char* out_path) {
    int ret;
    unsigned have;
    z_stream stream;
    FILE* out_file;
    gzFile in_gz_file;
    unsigned char in[CHUNK];
    unsigned char out[CHUNK];
    int err_no = 0;
    const char* emsg;

    stream.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    stream.zfree = Z_NULL;
    stream.opaque = Z_NULL;
    stream.avail_in = 0;
    stream.next_in = Z_NULL;
    ret = inflateInit2(&stream, (32 + MAX_WBITS));
    if (ret != Z_OK) {
        zlib_error(ret);
        return -1;
    }

    out_file = fopen(out_path, "wb");
    in_gz_file = gzopen(gz_path, "rb");

    if (out_file == NULL) {
        printf("%s", "couldn't open the output file");
        inflateEnd(&stream);
        return -1;
    }
    if (in_gz_file == NULL) {
        printf("%s", "couldn't open the input file as gzip");
        fclose(out_file);
        inflateEnd(&stream);
        return -1;
    }

    do {
        stream.avail_in  = gzfread(in, 1, CHUNK, in_gz_file);
        if (stream.avail_in == 0) {
            emsg = gzerror(in_gz_file, &err_no);
            if (err_no < 0 || err_no == 2) {
                printf("Error when reading %s", emsg);
                zlib_error(err_no);
                inflateEnd(&stream);
                fclose(out_file);
                gzclose(in_gz_file);
                return -1;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        stream.next_in = in;
        do {
            stream.avail_out = CHUNK;
            stream.next_out = out;

            ret = inflate(&stream, Z_SYNC_FLUSH);
            printf("Return value of inflate: %i\n", ret);
            assert(ret != Z_STREAM_ERROR);
            switch (ret) {
                case Z_NEED_DICT:
                    ret = Z_DATA_ERROR;
                case Z_DATA_ERROR:
                case Z_MEM_ERROR:
                    printf("Error: %s\n", stream.msg);
                    inflateEnd(&stream);
                    zlib_error(ret);
                    fclose(out_file);
                    gzclose(in_gz_file);
                    return -1;
            }

            have = CHUNK - stream.avail_out;
            if (fwrite(out, 1, have, out_file) != have || ferror(out_file)) {
                inflateEnd(&stream);
                zlib_error(ret);
                fclose(out_file);
                gzclose(in_gz_file);
                return -1;
            }
        } while (stream.avail_out == 0);
    } while (ret != Z_STREAM_END);

    fclose(out_file);
    gzclose(in_gz_file);
    inflateEnd(&stream);
    return ret == Z_STREAM_END ? Z_OK : Z_DATA_ERROR;
}
```

Comment: `gzread` reads compressed data and uncompresses it to the destination. You don't need any additional decompression code.

Comment: So I am trying to double uncompressing it using gzread() and inflate() (which errors then as trying to uncompress already uncompressed data, ...)?

Comment: Thanks @RetiredNinja that was it! If you post it as answer I can accept the solution.

Comment: yes, you are trying to double uncompress it